# Why wont my application cache using OutputCache

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, caching, outputcache

I am at a loss to explain why my application is not caching the front page.

I have placed a datestamp on the page: `@DateTime.Now`

Here is the Home controller action

```
[OutputCache(Duration = 60)]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}
```

**However, caching is not working and the front page keeps changing the date.**

I have tried to reduce the front page and associated layouts to bare minimum so only the DateTime.Now was being stamped.

I have inspected all base controllers for any disable caching code.

Also inspected the global.asax

Inspected the web.config for any caching configuration - none.

Inspected with fiddler. Here is the response header.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: public, no-cache="Set-Cookie", max-age=60
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Expires: Wed, 04 Mar 2015 05:20:45 GMT
Last-Modified: Wed, 04 Mar 2015 05:19:45 GMT
Vary: *
```

I have also tried different browsers that would not have any local caching settings modified.

Have also tried deploying the app to a stage server so it is not run on my dev machine.

Have tried making a fresh asp.net mvc application. That did work. Somewhat helpful in at least telling me the technology works.

Where could the problem be?

Comment: I am not sure if this helps you, but if your "front page" happens to be using [Authorize] attribute (it could be registered as a global filter), [Authorize] attribute will disable output caching.

Comment: ty, good tip. Not using Authorize and checked for any other attributes down the controller inheritance.

Comment: Relying on the browser to cache `text/html` in a way that it will not even *re-request* it from the server is not likely to work in most modern browsers. If you want to see your time stamp not changing for 60 seconds, store the cached copy in the server: `[OutputCache(Duration = 60, Location = OutputCacheLocation.Server)]`.

Answer (score 2):

A couple of things to check:

1. If this is on your production environment, check output caching is enabled on IIS.  See [this page](http://www.iis.net/learn/manage/managing-performance-settings/configure-iis-7-output-caching).
2. Try switching the location of your cache to help narrow down where the issue lies:

e.g.

```
[OutputCache(Duration = 60, Location = OutputCacheLocation.Server)]
[OutputCache(Duration = 60, Location = OutputCacheLocation.Client)]
```

3. Check your web.config for any [caching] entries which may override default behaviour

Comment: hi Nick, thanks for the suggestions. Think I have found the problem, just don't know why yet and will post the answer when I do. Nutshell is Homt.Index action is overriding a base controller action. A regular Home.Contact action is caching.

Comment: I have installed Donut Caching and now my problem is resolved.